# Android multiple Loader for http request

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, loader

I m using Javascript and want to do something similar this in Android Java.

```
 //jquery
$.when(Ajax1, Ajax2, Ajax3)
    .done(function(response1){    
         // to do after all complete

         })
     .fail(function(err){
         // err

         });


// Or AsyncJs
async.parallel([
    function(callback){

     },
    function(callback){

    }
],
 // optional final callback
 function(err, results){

 });
```

in Android I know Loader and read all of this. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Now I know how to load just only 1 loadTask.

**BUT if i want to load many tasks  ex : ProfileTask, OrderTask, ProductTask,...

If all complete then display the UI,

 If one of them fail to load then alert and click to retry.**

Comment: so call `LoaderManager#initLoader(id, args, callback);` multiple times with different ids

Comment: @pskink I understand use many ids.  But how to do the concept, when all of them complete or 1-loader fail then cancel all remaining loaders and notify Caller.

Comment: and what is the problem with it? just invoke N loaders and in `onLoadComplete` check the status, if anyone failed then cancel the rest of pending loaders and notify caller with the failure, if not, check if the number of completed loaders == N, if so notify caller with the succes

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a different approach. Take a look at [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or Javas Executors class, call your "xxxTasks" from there and communicate the result through an Broadcast/EventBus back to your activity.